# Google In-App-Billing vs Paid Applications confusion

Tags: android, google-play

I have published free to download apps to google play store before. Now I'm going to publish a app, which users need pay to download and use it.

Is there any additional steps to complete in my application to launch my app as a priced app?

I have little bit confused regarding this because when I'm searching about this, I found about [Google Play In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html). for **In-app Billing** programmer should import library and do some coding part. so I have confused about launching my app as a priced app.

What are the additional steps I should complete before launching the app as a priced app?

What are the best practices to follow when launching the app as a priced app?

Comment: Convert free app to paid app? or upload a new Paid App ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Upload a new app as a paid app.

Answer (score 2):

When the users dont have to be able to buy stuff in app you can ignore this.

Comment: what should i ignore ?

Comment: The part with the In-App-Billing. This is only relevant if the customer should be able to "buy" some content in your app. Otherwise you can just publish your App :)

Answer (score 2):

This is related just to those applications which need to manage payments inside the app. If you want just sell your app through Google Play ignore that part.